# Kafka Streams error state during rolling update with the same topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I meet with this strange behavior: during application rolling update (3 nodes) canary pod failed, because all Kafka streams have died. More interestingly, the investigation showed the root cause was:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer was assigned partitions [my-service-KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006-repartition-0, my-service-KSTREAM-MAP-0000000002-repartition-0] 
which didn't correspond to subscription request [first_topic, second_topic, third_topic]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.handleAssignmentMismatch(ConsumerCoordinator.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:353)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:941)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:846)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774)
```

these repartition topics are existing internal topics from running topology. Ok, but why it failed?

One more clue was in this log:

```
INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer 
clientId=my-service-f4d2b970-4a28-4221-b64f-5440c837203c-StreamThread-1-consumer, 
groupId=my-service] 
Subscribed to pattern: 'my-service-KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000012-repartition|my-service-KSTREAM-MAP-0000000011-repartition|
first_topic|second_topic|third_topic'
```

It shows that Kafka Streams created different internal topics (different names) and used it as a subscription pattern. 
It's possible only when the topology is changing: reorganizing operations cause internal topics renaming (if no name overrides are present). 
In my case no topology-related changes were present. Even more, there are the same dependency versions.

So, what could provoke internal topics renaming in this case?

**Notes**:

- kafka streams lib version = 2.3.0
- Topics replication factor = 3
- Topics partitions = 2

Comment: Can you show your code, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't show you the source code. But I can show you the topology or configuration. The main point is that rolling updates like this were successful a lot of times

Comment: Okay, properties would be useful. Anyway, if you didn't change the Topology, no internal topics should change, however it also doesn't hurt to cleanup internal topics using the application reset tool

Comment: Clean up internal topics causes losing lots of data. Let's imagine the service is in production and handles a huge amount of data. After that, you're calculating analytics based on that data. Reset tool or simply changing clientId (change topology) means you'll miss important data. I'm asking about the safe way how to handle this issue. And moreover, why it had happened

Comment: Your input sources are not deleted, so why is there loss? Ideally, your pipeline should be idempotent such that the internal, intermediate topics can be rebuilt from some source of truth. (assuming the input topic's retention has not dropped data itself)

Comment: If you're talking about changing offsets, then yes, it can be possible. But it should be done with caution to prevent processing events twice as a deduplication mechanism can be absent

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing offsets. I did say that your processing should be idempotent, such as a true changelog of events, such that picking any moment will rebuild the eventual, final state the same way, every time.

Comment: Can you compare the `TopologyDescription` of the old and new topology, to verify that the topology did in fact not change?

Comment: Topology description shows that topologies are the same